# Make local Centos server at home public, safe?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, port-forwarding, http, centos-7

So I have a Centos local server at home. I want to make it accessible over the internet (public). I know I have to forward port 80 (HTTP) and 21 (FTP).

My main question is, is this safe? Or should I just buy a VPS. I really like to setup my own server etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ftp is the first thing that will get your machine compromised. Never open ftp. Use instead ssh and sftp.

Install and configure something like fail2ban or denyhosts.

You must enable selinux and make apache/nginx work with selinux.

Close all other services. Also you could change the default port for ssh.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will use sftp then, so I can change the ssh port in centOS to for example 190 and then open port 190 on my router? @cristi

Comment: I don't know your router configuration, but you may also need to forward port 190 to your centos host

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend making my own server or just buy a vps?

Comment: It will be the same thing regarding the configuration and hardening of the server. I would recommend a VPS, mostly because it's somebody else problem to keep the machine up, take care of power outage, disks failing, etc.

Comment: That is true, but what if you are a guy that wants to learn besides coding also how to manage a server in a safe way without letting hackers go into your router.

Comment: Why do you need to put the machine on internet? You can play with a Vm on your computer or with your computer, but not allow access from outside.

Comment: I create applications that links to an API, If I want to use it on my phone. I need connection from outside.

Comment: Then I don't know any other way then locking your server.

Comment: I think a VM is maybe a good idea, will try it out but if I am offline I.E airplane can I still ssh to centos from my laptop that has the VM? I've heard of host-only network.

Comment: Sure, you can forward ports from your host to the VM.